# Error in my First JSF Program with Tomcat and Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsf, maven, tomcat

Im a Totally new in Java and JSF. I'm using eclipse Indigo and Tomcat 6.0.3 and JSF 2.0. Iam using the Maven and deploying the wars to server.

I configured the server in the Eclipse and i normally get the apache page in Localhost:8080.

But When i try to access my page like localhost:8080/ContactFormJSF/, I get the Message as

```
HTTP Status 404 - /ContactFormJSF/
type Status report
message /ContactFormJSF/
description The requested resource (/ContactFormJSF/) is not avilable.
```

This is code like, what there in Adduser.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"      
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>JSF 2.0 Hello World</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h3>JSF 2.0 Hello World Example - hello.xhtml</h3>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

I  Have even configured the "`servlet-mapping`","`welcome-file-list`" in the Web.xml

My web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>AddUser.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

<session-config>
      <session-timeout>15</session-timeout> 
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Comment: I have added my web.xml above and the Jars are there in lib folder and the url iam using is localhost:8080/ContactFormJSF/

Comment: Have a look : http://balusc.blogspot.ro/2011/01/jsf-20-tutorial-with-eclipse-and.html. This should help you.

Comment: @Khirthan..Your `web.xml` configuration seeem's to be correct. you are missing some part of `jar`. Ensure the reqired jar under `WEB-INF/lib`

Comment: @kark I have all the jars of jsf namely jsf-impl.jar, jsf-api.jar, jstl.jar, commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar, commons-chain-1.1.jar,commons-collections.jar,commons-logging-1.0.4.jar,commons-digester-1.8.jar. should i add any other than this??

Comment: You said you are using Maven, why are you deploying jars manually? can you please post pom.xml code?

Comment: Iam not deplying the jars manually, Iam just deploying the Final War output in the Server. My pom.xml has lots of contents with Plugins, Repositories, Dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following Conditions

1. Check the required jars inserted under `WEB-INF/lib` directory(Strongly recommended)
2. Check the `servlet` has been mapped in `Web.xml`
3. Check your invoking correct `URL` pattern in browser